# Comparing an integer field in each record of a table to the sum of associated records in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have these two tables: Product and Storage

Product has a ProductId, and a QuantityAvailable for each record

Storage has a LocationId, ProductId and QuantityAvailable for each record (ProductId is a FK to the product table). A 'ProductId' can be stored in multiple 'LocationId's, therefore ProductId and LocationId make up a compound primary key.

What I want is an SQL query that is able to determine if a 'Product' is in storage, and if so, if the 'Quantity' in cumulative storage is less than the 'QuantityAvailable'.

To put things simply, I want a listing of all the 'ProductId's in the Product table where the sum of the 'Quantity' of all the associated entries in the Storage table is less than the 'QuantityAvailable' of the Product Table.

How can I achieve this (without changing the table structure)?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query will give you the sum of the quantities for each product:

```
select ProductID, sum(Quantity) as ProductQuantity
from
    Storage
group by
    ProductID
```

Now you simply need to use that query as a derived table, join to it, and compare your 2 quantities:

```
select
    *
from
    Product p
    inner join (
        select ProductID, sum(Quantity) as ProductQuantity
        from
            Storage
        group by
            ProductID) q
        on  p.ProductID = q.ProductID
where
    q.ProductQuantity < p.QuantityAvailable
```

Comment: Thanks, I got this to work, but how would I get it to list ALL my product Ids from the product table, even if there is no match in the Storage table? (Should show NULL for ProductQUantity)

Comment: Change the inner join to a left join.

Comment: Was just about to post that I figured it out with the left join. Thanks man.